# When i type a code, R is just waiting, it does not give even errors. How can i solve?

Tags: r

When i try to type and run any code on R, it is only waiting. Neither it let me to type new one nor it give errors.Here is the problem. It does not produce new ">" to type codes.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as screenshots - copy the code into your question so we can run it our own sessions.

Also, which specific line is it not returning the R prompt? Are you just running this file all at once? Have you tried running it line by line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rstudio menue, go to Session menue and click restart R.
[image]